# How do I do the correct Laplace transform of this function

Tags: laplace-transform

How do I find the Laplace transform of
$$  f (t) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 0 \leq t < \frac{ \pi}{2} \\
\sin(t) & \, t \geq \frac{ \pi}{2}  \\
\end{array}
\right. $$

Thought about using the shift theorem $ L \{ f(t-a)H(t-a) \}(s)= e^{-as} L \{ f(t) \} (s)$

or will it just be the integral $ \int_{ \frac{ \pi}{2}}^{ \infty}e^{-st} \sin(t) dt $ ?

Comment: Yes, your first idea is on the right track. You have$$f(t)=H\left(t-\frac\pi2\right)\sin t=H\left(t-\frac\pi2\right)\cos\left(t-\frac\pi2\right)$$assuming $H(t)$ denotes the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). Not to say your second idea is wrong, but there's no reason to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: thank you ! solving the integral $ \int_0^{ \infty} e^{-st} H(t- \frac{ \pi }{2} \cos( t - \frac{ \pi }{2} ) dt= \int_{ \frac{ \pi}{2}}^{ \infty} e^{-st} \cos( t - \frac{ \pi}{2}) dt = \frac{1}{s^2+1} $ is this correct ? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using the shifting property:

$$\mathcal L(f(t))(x)=e^{-\pi s/2}\mathcal L(\cos t)(s)=e^{-\pi s/2}\frac s{s^2+1}$$

or directly:

$$\mathcal L(f(t)(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)\,dt=\int_{\pi/2}^\infty e^{-st}\sin t\,dt=\left.-\frac{\sin t\,e^{-st}}s\right|_{\pi/2}^\infty+\frac1s\int_{\pi/2}^\infty\cos t\,e^{-st}\,dt=$$

$$\frac{e^{-\pi s/2}}s+\frac1s\left[\left.-\frac{\cos te^{-st}}s\right|_{\pi/2}^\infty-\frac1s\int_{\pi/2}^\infty\sin t\, e^{-st}\,dt\right]\implies$$

$$\left(1+\frac1{s^2}\right)\int_{\pi/2}^\infty e^{-st}\sin t\,dt=\frac{e^{-\pi s/2}}s\implies \int_{\pi/2}^\infty e^{-st}\sin t\,dt=e^{-\pi s/2}\frac s{s^2+1}$$

The second way is a good practice in improper integrals and integration by parts...